# Showing that the polar cone is closed

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $K$ be a cone. I know that the polar cone $K^0$ can be shown to be closed by writing it as the intersection of closed sets. However, I want to do it by taking a sequence $(x_k) \subset K^0$ such that $x_k \to x$, and showing that necessarily $x \in K^0$.

So far, I tried to show this by contradiction assuming $x \notin K^0$, but I´m stuck at proving that there must exist $M$ such that $x_k \notin K^0$ for $k \geq M$.

Comment: You want to show the polar cone is closed, so why are you taking a sequence in $K$ rather than in $K^o$?

Comment: @angryavian: Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: A proof by sequences will end up similar to the intersection proof. The defining equation must hold for each element of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u \in K$. We know that $\langle u, x_k \rangle \leq 0$ for all positive integers $k$. It follows that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty } \langle u, x_k \rangle = \langle u, x \rangle \leq 0.
$$
This shows that $\langle u, x \rangle \leq 0$ for all $u \in K$, which means that $x \in K^\circ$.